# Compare strings containing font icons

Tags: javascript

**Note to people who pretend to be Moderators:**
Do not dislike if you could not understand this question. It has enough information enough details and very useful to people who use font-icons in JS

I am trying to compare two strings that contain `font-icons`, but it is failed. I have tried comparing like below

```
a === b
a == b // Though Browser will do my conversion job
btoa(a) == btoa(b) // Browser scolded me.
```

Are there any alternative ways?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Q3pH/)

Comment: Could you add the string values please.

Comment: @Hatsjoem Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4Q3pH/

Comment: Who could dislike this question while this is useful to everyone who code JS

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle, `element.innerText` is returning undefined, hence it is failing.

Use `element.textContent` instead. Also, since your div contains `&#xf000;`, you'll need to take some extra precaution in some browsers since it might try and convert it into an object of some sort. (Currently happening on my browser)

Comment: In Mozilla we may need textContent. Was checking in Chrome and thought  of OK :)